# Grey rectangle instead of the splash Qt

Tags: c++, qt, splash-screen

I built and executed the application (code bellow), and the splash screen shows gray, instead of the image. I didn't know where is the problem although the path of the image is correct.

This is my main.cpp:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include<QSplashScreen>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])

{
QApplication app(argc, argv);

QPixmap pixmap(":/images/splash.png");
QSplashScreen splash(pixmap);
splash.setMask(pixmap.mask());  
splash.show();
app.processEvents();
sleep(5);

MainWindow window;
window.show();
app.connect(&app, SIGNAL(lastWindowClosed()), &app, SLOT(quit()));
splash.finish(&window);

return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "during the build process it shows me always a grey rectangle instead of the splash"?

Comment: when I run the application instead to see the splashscreen before the the main window ..I only see a grey rectangle and after my mainwindow
@BЈовић

Comment: How do you build? Did you parse and compile resources? Try loading the image from a file instead.

Comment: I'm in the Qt creator IDE , I only click in the run button .....i didn't understand what do u mean by loading the image from a file ?
@BЈовић

Comment: `QPixmap pixmap(":/images/splash.png");` - you are using an image from the resources. Put `QPixmap pixmap("images/splash.png");` instead (of course, use correct path).

Comment: i replaced with this :QPixmap pixmap("images/splash.png");
but always the same problem :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options :

- you either didn't parse and compile the resource file (with [rcc](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/rcc.html) to parse)
- or you put wrong path in the qrc file to your image (see [qt resources](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/resources.html)), or you didn't add it at all

As I said, try to use an image from a disk. If it displays fine, then it is one of the above problem.

Comment: i use also image in the mainwindow and they are shown to me ...so the path to my image ressource is correct in the qrc file

Comment: Thx i found the problem , I forget to add the splash image in the qrc file with the other image ...thx a lot :)
@BЈовић